# How to hide a specific category name everywhere on this theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

​Hello,

I know this isn't a new topic and it has been already discussed but I need to hide the **name** of a specific post category named "Nolink" from anywhere on the website and after trying several things, nothing seems to work.

I don't know if it's because the theme I'm using: http://bridge92.qodeinteractive.com/ but can't find the way to make it work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: delete it. but if you want more specific solution, then need to provide more details, such as where that category name appears, how you want to hide it and etc

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well. I don't need to hide the post but only this specific category name. There are some categories that I only use to hide or show some posts on the feed but I don't actually want their name printed on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution via editing the functions.php file:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-4' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

What this will do is omit a specific post category from the global get post query. Be sure to replace the "4" with the ID of your category you want to omit. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to keep seeing the post but not that specific category name ? Sorry if I didn't explain it correctly before

Comment: Well it really depends where you are also trying to hide the category name. The solution could be endless here, WP has several templates. You need to try to iron out which one you're working with and see about doing one of two things:

a) Writing PHP conditional logic to omit outputting the specific category if it matches with the one you don't want to output.

b) Using JavaScript to conduct a global find/replace on your page after it's loaded. Remove the category text from the div that would be outputting it, so it's no longer there.